# How to update a database in phpmyAdmin using matlab?

Tags: php, mysql, matlab

I wanted to update a database inside the phpmyAdmin however, an error keeps popping up and I tried many solution but still it does not work. The code:

```
conn=database('iprintstatuses', 'root', '', 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver',     'jdbc:mysql://localhost/');
setdbprefs('DataReturnFormat','cellarray');
paper_loader_on_status = fetch(conn,'SELECT paper_loader FROM statuses');
paper_loader = paper_loader_on_status {1};
newz= {'1'};
whereclause = 'where paper_loader = 1';
if (paper_loader == 1)
    pause(1);
    update(conn, 'statuses', 'new_paper_loader', newz, whereclause);
end
```

The error:

Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.

**Error** in database/update (line 125)

```
updateFields = [updateFields fieldNames{j}]; %#ok
```

**Error** in SQLaccessing (line 10)

```
update(conn, 'statuses', 'new_paper_loader', newz, whereclause);
```

How to solve this error?

[image: This is the image of the table. It is really a simple table :( *It is an integer*]

Comment: instead of `newz` and `whereclause` in you update function call, can you try putting in `'1'` and `'where paper_loader = 1'` and tell us what error you get? It seems that newz as you define it is a cell array, but whereclause is just a String. So I wonder if some part of your update function does not like the format.

Comment: It said that input data must be cell array, matrix, structure, dataset or table

Comment: did you write this `update` function? It looks like your input is choking on something that we could not see.

Comment: I just followed the format for this update function of matlab.

Comment: Okay, I had a closer look at the function, you are calling it wrong, the column name should be a cell {'new_paper_loader'}.

Comment: I tried that also. However, it said that the input data must be cell array, matrix, structure, dataset or table again. I also tried {'1'} but it said: No method 'setInt' with matching signature found for class 'com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4PreparedStatement'.

Comment: yes so using {'1'} and {column name} actually worked, now it's just your update query that needs fixing.

Comment: I also added a photo of the simple table in the database on my question. Sorry if I haven't attached it earlier. But  that might help.

Comment: What type of entry did you set for new_paper_loader in your DB? Is it Int or String? It seems that is what's causing the error - meaning that if it is INT then instead of {'1'} just set {1}.

Comment: It seems that you got it lol. The error is if it is int or string. I missed that one O.o Thank you very much O.o. Gonna post the answer lol

Answer (score 0):

Since the new_paper_loader is an integer...the data must be an integer :D

```
 conn=database('iprintstatuses', 'root', '', 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver',      'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/');
setdbprefs('DataReturnFormat','cellarray');
paper_loader_on_status = fetch(conn,'SELECT paper_loader FROM statuses');
paper_loader = paper_loader_on_status {1};
whereclause = 'where paper_loader = 1';
if (paper_loader == 1)
    pause(1);
    update(conn, 'statuses', {'new_paper_loader'}, {1}, 'where paper_loader = 1');
end
```

Thanks to GameOfThrows for figuring out a very simple mistake :D

Comment: hahahaha but at least you helped me to figure it out through a step-by-step process :D